# F# Implement base class

Tags: c#, f#, base-class

I'm new to F# and I wanted to create an F# Forms Application. But the Problem that I have at the moment, is that I don't know how to implement a base class. In C# I would do it like that

```
namespace Test_Form
{
    public class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

But how do I make it in F# so that my Forms is a module and not a type

I already tryed

```
open System
open System.Windows.Forms

type Form1() = 
    inherit Form()
```

but that would result in

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1() : this()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Your last snippet is exactly equivalent to your first snippet. What's the problem?

Comment: That i can't acces this.Controls or anything like that in F#, it says "The namespace or the Module "this" is not defined."

Comment: Q (offtopic): why not WPF?

Comment: @Silent3241 you should have mentioned the problem in the question. We can't read minds, you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where you would use the constructor method in C#

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

In F#, quoting [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/classes),

> The do-bindings section includes code to be executed upon object
>   construction.

you would

```
type Form1() =
    inherit Form()

    do // stuff
```

For example:

```
type Form1() as this =
    inherit Form()

    do this.Click.Add(fun args -> printfn "%s" <| args.ToString())
```

Comment: But how do I access this.* because when I try it like your code i get still the error message "The Namespace or the Module "this" is not defined"

Comment: @Silent3241 You need to change `type Form1() =` to `type Form1() as this =`.